# Adding pluralize to .html.erb causes error in Rails functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working through *Agile Web Development With Rails* for Rails 3.0, and I'm at a point where running **rake test:functionals** gives a successful result.

When I add the following code to my .html.erb and re-run the same command, I get errors all over the place.

**Code:**

```
<span>
     <% if session[:counter] > 5 %>
        You've visited this page <%= pluralize(session[:counter], 'time')  %>
     <% end %>
</span>
```

**Error:**

```
 ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass
 ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `:counter` member of your session is not being properly set, so `session[:counter]` evaluated to `nil`. Make sure that you're properly setting your session variables in your test. For example, `get(:show, {'id' => "12"}, {'user_id' => 5})` would set `session[:user_id]` to 5.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers for more info.